# android app doesnt open after installiation

Tags: java, android, google-play

My new android app can download from the google play but doesn't appear in my downloaded apps. When i download it from the play store usually there is an option to 'open' the app as well as 'uninstall', only the uninstall button is visible. From my emulator, when i run the program everything is work perfectly, but when i try to open it from the emulator, it seems like i never installed the app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.viral"
    android:versionCode="4"
    android:versionName="1.7" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.viral.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
               <data
                android:host="t4jsample"
                android:scheme="oauth" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
</manifest>
```

if more information is needed just comment, help would be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this piece of snippet is responsible for this issue,

```
<data
            android:host="t4jsample"
            android:scheme="oauth" />
```

Don't give this filter inside laucher activity.
Or
You can try something like this,

```
 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="t4jsample"
                    android:scheme="oauth" />
            </intent-filter>
```